# Spring Maven - context configuration in resources folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jetty

As I found in other question at stackoverflow, it is better to keep the configuration of spring in src/main/resources folder. However when I use mvn jetty:run it tries to load context configuration from WEB-INF whatever I'm typing into web.xml. I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/easyscrum-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/easyscrum-servlet.xml]
```

What should I do to force servlet to load config from classpath instead of web-inf?

Comment: you might have specified this path in your `web.xml`

Comment: Please edit your post showing the relevant portions of `web.xml` (the dispatcher servlet configuration and any context loader listener configuration).

Comment: you should probably include the entire stacktrace as well in your question.

Comment: You can use the classpath: prefix to load from the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

To load spring config context files from classpath you have to prefix the path with `classpath:`

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```